# Why am I accruing "consecutive days" on Meta Stack Exchange if I didn't visit?

Tags: bug, consecutive-days

I know there have been 1000 complaints about consecutive days, but I'm going to turn those on their ear for a moment.

On Meta Stack Exchange, it lists me as having visited the site for 13 straight days, but I was on vacation for a good part of the last couple of weeks and had spotty internet at best on most of those days.

I do have MSE open on my tablet, which I had with me while traveling, but I only connected it to Wi-Fi on 2 of those days. I have a bunch of other SE sites open on the tablet as well, but it didn't maintain the consecutive days on those sites.

I use Firefox 31 on both the tablet and desktop, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Was your desktop (home, work, etc) *on* during this time? From memory, doesn't firefox refresh frequently-used bookmarks periodically for fast startup?

Comment: The desktop was powered down the entire time. I had FF on my phone, and Sync was on, but I didn't have MSE open on my phone either. If the server was picking up an open instance of a tab somewhere, I figure that would reflect on my other sites that were open as well.

Comment: Actually, the only day you missed was the 9th; but bizarrely, haproxy only sees activity up to the 8th and from the 18th; I'm investigating where the 10-17th came from...

Comment: Those dates are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access between the 10th and 17th (inclusive) was all recorded from an application (the official SE for Android app); the access *outside of that range* was on the web-site. Are you sure your device didn't connect automatically when you were passing shops etc? (for example, my 'phone is configured to use hot-spots that have an affiliation with my ISP). I could tell you the IP addresses you came in from if you like, but I don't want to post those uninvited.

Comment: The app must have been what was doing it, but I didn't have it on every day (and I would force close it to save batteries).  I didn't realize using the app would count on all the sites, though, so that's the missing link.

Comment: I figured that I would have to view a question from the site for it to count as a visit on the app.  Anyway, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @jonsca a "visit" is viewing any page other than the home page. So if the app looks at your profile page (for example) that would count as a visit.

Comment: @ChrisF Makes sense.  I mainly checked for notifications, but something must have registered.