# Wrongfully received badge... again

Tags: bug, badges

For the [second time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285509/300788), I've received a "consecutive days" badge in error (gold this time!).

The first time I reported this, it was brushed off and incorrectly closed as a duplicate.

I just received the "fanatic" (100 days) version. Since I know this is an error, I figured I'd report it again. Hopefully someone actually reads the post this time before closing it.

Facts:

- I did **not** visit Code Review everyday for 100 days. I visit it *maybe* once a week.
- No, I don't have some script running that auto-checks CR. I almost exclusively use the app (Android) whenever I use SE.
- No, I don't have anything else on my phone (other apps, widgets) that query CR.
- No one else has access to my account.  My SE account is tied to Google+, and I have 2-step verification in place, and do regular activity monitoring. On top of that, every computer I use SE from is entirely under my control; locked behind a password.
- CR is in my "favorites" in the app, but if that were a factor, I'd expect to be getting badges from Programming Golf, Arqade, SO, Software Engineering and Skeptics, and I'm not.
- No, it isn't because my phone was querying the app without my knowledge. I restart my phone everyday, and regularly close open apps. On top of that, if this were the cause, I'd expect credit for SO, not CR.
- ... No, I did **not** visit Code Review everyday for 100 days. I visit it *maybe* once a week.

If this gets swept under the rug again, whatever, I tried. I just thought you guys should be aware there appears to be a bug in the system somewhere.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238424/why-am-i-accruing-consecutive-days-on-meta-stack-exchange-if-i-didnt-visit

Comment: You should have tagged the quetsion 'feature-request'.  I had a similar problem but the other way around.  I had x consecutive days and my cookies were eaten by a rat.  The next time I looked I had 2 consecutive days.  Is that fanatic or what?

Comment: @jonsca Thanks. Added a point addressing that.

Comment: @user6035379 That sucks. I suppose I should count myself as lucky (although, come to think of it, I think I should have received a badge for SO by now, and haven't.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: ... really?

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes. **Something** is visiting the site on user's behalf, I'm pretty sure it's the same thing. Only SE staff has chance to figure what's causing this, and no need to leave around more than one same report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's *my* post, and I referenced it at the top. Please don't close this one like you did the last one just to get it out of the way; that doesn't help anything. I fully addressed the other post in this one and broke down why this issue is not a duplicate of the post that it was closed as a duplicate of. This may be a issue with the app, but that doesn't mean it's a duplicate of either my other post, or the scripted badge post.

Comment: @Carcigenicate your older post has been reopened since it obviously wasn't a duplicate. This *is* the same issue, your title says so "...again" and the body says "for the second time" so it's clearly a duplicate. You can edit your original post to add new details.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so what if it's your post? It makes it even more obviously a duplicate. Whatever bug (?) is causing this, it's still not fixed. No point to keep reporting it. (better edit/update the original.)

Comment: @Cai oh, if the other post has been reopened, then ya, I can see that. Honestly though, I think this post contains more details than the other one. The other one could probably be nixed instead.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, I didn't realize the other one had been reopened.

Comment: There's no need to delete either, this question will still be here and it will still be seen, closing it as a duplicate is just acknowledging that it's a reoccurrence of the same bug

Comment: @Cai Sure, then I guess that works.

Comment: Voted to close as a dupe